# Using distinct with an observable

Tags: json, angular, observable

I am trying to filter out duplicates by using .distinct() in my observable but it does not do anything and I have no errors....

```
    this.settingsService.getGuruQueries().subscribe(queries => { 
of<any>(queries).pipe(distinct((p: any) => p['book']), ).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

My console.log display duplicates:

```
{book: "XBIL", grid: "NATGRI", concept: "STT_XBIL", query: "XBIL_NATGRI", customer: "A", …}
{book: "XBIL", grid: "IT-ANY", concept: "STT_XBIL", query: "XBIL_IT-ANY", customer: "A", …}
{book: "IBIL", grid: "NATGRI", concept: "STT_IBIL", query: "IBIL_NATGRI", customer: "A", …}
{book: "IMIL", grid: "IT-ANY", concept: "STT_IMIL", query: "IMIL_IT-ANY", customer: "A", …}
{book: "IDAFR", grid: "RTE", concept: "STT_IDAFR", query: "IDAFR_RTE", customer: "A", …}
{book: "IDCOM", grid: "RTE", concept: "STT_XFIL", query: "XFIL_RTE", customer: "A", …} ...
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: What is `this.distinctBooks`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are not passing values individually, but all at once.

Say your `distinctBooks` data is an array. If you pass it to distinct, it's `name` property is `undefined`. So even if you later change the thing, it's name is still going to be `undefined` (as it's just an array, you don't usually give them names).

## Observable `distinct`

`distinct` wants an array of emitted values, not single value. I think something like this would work for you (assuming a lot on your component):

```
this.settingsService.getGuruQueries().subscribe(queries => { 
  from<any>(queries).pipe(distinct((p: any) => p['book']), ).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Note that I've used `from` instead of your `of`.

## Distinct array items

An alternative would be to simply filter unique values from the books array normally, no need for observables there:

```
this.settingsService.getGuruQueries().pipe(map(queries => Array.from(new Set(queries ))))
.subscribe();
```

See examples [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-distinct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

---

*Note:* you're nesting subscribes in your example. You can avoid it by using `pipe/map` there (ignore the fact that the example is not working):

```
this.settingsService.getGuruQueries()
    .pipe(
         map(queries =>  
              of<any>(queries).pipe(distinct((p: any) => p['book']))
    )
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which version of Angular/Rxjs you use. So, assuming `distinct` exists in the version you use, the issue is, when you do distinct, you would be checking  of an observable is distinct i.e. if the new observable value is same  as old are exactly same, don't emit anything. The basic concept is explained [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html).

What you want to do, is actually a basic remove duplicates from the actual array object. For this, you will need to write your own logic.